# Why does this swap function behave inconsistently in heap implementation?

Tags: c++, heap

Here is the heap before decreasing 15 to 13.

```
               |                
              99                
       /               \        
      10              15        
   /       \       /       \    
   7       9      11      14    
 /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \  
 1   4   3   8   2   6   5  12
```

This is the heap after decreasing the key of 15 to 13. The problem you can see is that 13 does not bubble down as expected. (swap seems to work for bubble up)

```
Decreasing the key 15 to 13
Heap Array:99 10 13 7 9 11 14 1 4 3 8 2 6 12 5 

               |                
              99                
       /               \        
      10              13        
   /       \       /       \    
   7       9      11      14    
 /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \  
 1   4   3   8   2   6  12   5
```

These are the supporting code to achieve the decreasing of a key in heap.

It goes from decreasekey -> _lookfor -> _bubbleDown -> _swap.

```
template <class T>
void Heap<T>::_bubbleDown(int index) {
    if (index >= _n) return; // end of array
    while (_heap[index] < _heap[(index*2)+1] || _heap[index] < _heap[(index*2)+2]) { // index < child. bubble down the index.
        int biggerChild = ((_heap[(index*2)+1] > _heap[(index*2)+2]) ? (index*2)+1 : (index*2)+2);
        _swap(_heap[index], _heap[biggerChild]);
        index = biggerChild;
        if (index >= _n) break;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Heap<T>::_swap(int x, int y) {
    T temp;
    temp = _heap[x];
    _heap[x] = _heap[y];
    _heap[y] = temp;
}

template <class T>
int Heap<T>::_lookFor(T x){ // not a very good implementation, but just use this for now.
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<_n;i++)
        if (_heap[i] == x)
            return i;

    return -1;
}

template <class T>
void Heap<T>::decreaseKey(T from, T to)
{
    int index = _lookFor(from);
    if (index == -1) return;
    else {
        _heap[index] = to;
    }
    _bubbleDown(index);
}
```

I have tried debugging by printing flags. The function does enter the swap and a swap seems to be done. But somehow it is not reflected and I have no clue why.

Comment: Have you taken the time to single-step your code in the debugger? That should reveal the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: I think the problem is that you want `_swap(index, biggerChild);` The `_swap` function takes integers indexes, not values.

Comment: thank you...@JimMischel how careless of me.